# promise function working in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE Edge and IE11

Tags: javascript

I have written this funcction and seems to run well in Chrome and Firefox but seems not work in IE Edge or IE 11:

```
async function getJSONDataWithHeaders(url, methodType, responseType) {
            return new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open(methodType, url, true);
                xhr.responseType = responseType;
                setHeaders(xhr);
                xhr.onload = await function () {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        resolve(this.response);
                    }
                }
                xhr.send();
            }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
```

Here is how I call it:

```
getJSONDataWithHeaders("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", "GET", "json").then(function (result) {
 console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Just remove any async/await from this code, and it should work like a charm :)

Comment: I tried that and it did not work.

Comment: Taking them out, it actully fixed IE 11 but not Edge

Answer (score 0):

You could provide the `onload` as a parameter like so:

```js
function getJSONDataWithHeaders(url, methodType, responseType, onload) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    xhr.open(methodType, url, true);
    xhr.responseType = responseType;
    xhr.onload = onload
    xhr.send();
}
```

And then call it like this:

```js
getJSONDataWithHeaders('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', 'GET', 'json', function (progressEvent) {
    console.log(progressEvent.currentTarget.response)
})
```

Note the callback instead of a return value. As `sp00m` already suggested, `async/await` is not supported in IE. If you really need it, you could use [this babel plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator). It uses a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) function to polyfill `async/await`.

Comment: Yes, I tried his soluion a second time and I was able to fix IE 11 but not IE Edge.

Comment: Which version of edge are you using? `async/await` is supported since version 15. I don't see what else could cause issues.

Comment: Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1098.0

Comment: Weird. Could `fetch` be an alternative solution for you? E.g. like `fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => response.json()).then(console.log)`